ASP.NET Core action method not returning the id up to 2 digits(i.e 1, 22, 66) but return 3 digit(i.e 111, 222, 666)
I am have an action method Contact with return type (int) and taking (int id) as parameter.
The problem is that on this route when I pass two digit id, but it not shows, but it shows the id with three digits such as (111) but not showing (1)
enter image description here when I passing id = 1  it is not showing
enter image description here when I passing id = 111 it is showing
HomeController.cs
using _10_TagHelpersDemo.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace _10_TagHelpersDemo.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public int Contact(int id)
        {
            return id;
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}

Program.cs
namespace _10_TagHelpersDemo
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Add services to the container.
            builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}



Check by placing the breakpoint to see whether your Contact API action is hit and return the value as what it received. Also, you may try with Postman.

Do you any middleware running subsequently somewhere or do you have route configuration? I have tried to simulate your issue and working as expected in my side.

@MdFaridUddinKiron  Ok I will check it, thank you for your valuable time.

@MdFaridUddinKiron I have attached the the main file can you please check my middlewares (if you know which one is creating problem), it is the by default ASP .NET CORE MCV template's main Program.cs file

I have tested your scenario along with your controller and program.cs file seems correct and I got the expected output. Please check anything else which has not been shared here. By the way which version of asp.net core are you using? I have tested the scenario on both .NET 7 and 8 and working accordingly.

@MdFaridUddinKiron Ok, I will double check it; it may be my browser issue. Thanks for your response. I am using .NET Core 8: I am new to .NET switching from NodeJS to asp.

Okay, have a try and feel free to share if any further assistance needed. I have checked in two browser, edge and chrome and both working as expected.


I have attached the the main file can you please check my middlewares
(if you know which one is creating problem), it is the by default ASP
.NET CORE MCV template's main Program.cs file

Based on your shared code snippet and then after with the full program.cs file code, I have tried to simulate your issue. But its working exactly as expected.
I have investigated with 1 digit, 2 digits and more, all the cases produced the correct output.
In addition, the middleware code with the details of program.cs files also seems correct.
Here is the output of the investigation:





Note: According to your controller and program.cs file everything seems correct and I haven't got any issue while testing your scenario. Would you kindly double check if anything else you have which has not been shared. If you are checking output in browser, please clear the browser cache or check if anything other value is causing trouble.
